# jQuery storing and executing previous AJAX HTTP requests with every function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function which is called by the `onclick` event of a `<button>` element. The aim of the function is to pop up a modal dialog using bootstrap and display updated content using an AJAX call. The URL is different each time. The modal dialog is cleared of its content using the `hidden.bs.modal` event handler each time the box is closed.

The issue I'm experiencing is strange. The first request runs fine and displays the content as expected. Any subsequent calls are appended to the previous and the number of calls seem to be incrememted each time. A history of all the previous calls are executed. It's almost like the previous calls are all being cached.

For example:

**Click 1**

- Click 1 HTTP Request

**Click 2**

- Click 1 HTTP Request << This request should not run
- Click 2 HTTP Request

**Click 3**

- Click 1 HTTP Request << This request should not run
- Click 2 HTTP Request << This reuqest should not run
- Click 3 HTTP Request

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Button:

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showInModal('some/url/here/1022/17');">Button</a>
```

Function

```
//Modal dialog ajax

var loadingSpinner = '<div class="modal-content"><div class="model-body"><div class="loading-spinner"></div></div></div>';


$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', "#pageModal", function (e) {
    $(".modal .modal-dialog").html(loadingSpinner);
});


showInModal = (url) => {
    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', "#pageModal", function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (res) {
                $(".modal .modal-dialog").html(res);
            },
            cache: false

        });
    });

    $("#pageModal").modal('show');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a new `.on('shown.bs.modal'` event listener each time the function gets called. Each listener is making a request.

I don't think you really need that event for the ajax and could just show the modal in `success` callback. Or show the modal with a loading icon until request completes

```
showInModal = (url) => {
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (res) {
                $(".modal .modal-dialog").html(res);
                $("#pageModal").modal('show');
            },
            cache: false

        });    

}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes total sense now! I've refactored my code so that the event handler is not set each time the function is called.